# javascript match: How to get some specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

my problem is that i can not get numbers and "-" from all "[]"!
here is my input text:

```
sasa[1-10][2][1-12]
```

and here is my javascript:

```
m = input.val().toString().match(/(\[[0-9-]+\])/);
```

Comment: You have to clarify further. Is sasa[1-10][2][1-12] what you want to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
m = input.val().toString().match(/(\[[0-9-]+\])/g);
added global flag to match all matching values  ^
```